# Telerik Sitefinity - Sorting data selected

Tags: telerik, sitefinity

I has the code below to retrieve a data

```
Type dType = TypeResolutionService.ResolveType("Telerik.Sitefinity.DynamicTypes.Model.Schedule.ScheduleManagement");

        // This is how we get the collection of event items
        var myCollection = dynamicModuleManager.GetDataItems(dType).Where(i => i.Status == ContentLifecycleStatus.Live && i.Visible && i.GetValue<string>("Title").ToString() == channel + " Schedule").FirstOrDefault();
        // At this point myCollection contains the items from the the type


        return myCollection;
```

Any idea how I can sorting the data been selected?  Please help.

Comment: Check the forum reply on your thread at Sitefinity. http://www.sitefinity.com/developer-network/forums/developing-with-sitefinity-/sorting-data---dynamicmodulemanager-getdataitems#phdok1_mCU6S6k2Q8pP2PA Kind regards,
Daniel

Answer (score 1):

Firstly you need to remove the .FirstOrDefault() as this returns a single item (or null) not a collection.

To do sorting in linq you need to use .OrderBy()

eg, this would order by title.

```
Type dType = TypeResolutionService.ResolveType("Telerik.Sitefinity.DynamicTypes.Model.Schedule.ScheduleManagement");

    // This is how we get the collection of event items
    var myCollection = dynamicModuleManager.GetDataItems(dType).Where(i => i.Status == ContentLifecycleStatus.Live && i.Visible && i.GetValue<string>("Title").ToString() == channel + " Schedule").OrderBy(p=> p.GetValue<string>("Title"));
    // At this point myCollection contains the items from the the type


    return myCollection;
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to remove .FirstOrDefault() method.
Then in the query you need add the method ".AsEnumerable()", see the detail

```
var dType = TypeResolutionService.ResolveType("Telerik.Sitefinity.DynamicTypes.Model.Schedule.ScheduleManagement");

// This is how we get the collection of event items
var myCollection = dynamicModuleManager.GetDataItems(dType)
                                       .AsEnumerable()
                                       .Where(i => i.Status == ContentLifecycleStatus.Live && i.Visible 
                                                   && i.GetValue<string>("Title").ToString() == channel + " Schedule")
                                       .OrderBy(p=> p.GetValue<string>("Title"));
// At this point myCollection contains the items from the the type


return myCollection;
```

Note: if you don't push method ".AsEnumerable()", system will throw error.